# Unable to display data using ${data} in jsp while request.getAttribute("data") does return the value

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am trying to build a web application using servlet but facing this problem where i have just set my data in servlet class and fectching it in the jsp using ${}

JSP --->

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:out value="${data}"/>
<%= request.getAttribute("data") %>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet class:

```
public class Naveen extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Object data = "Some data, can be a String or a Javabean";
        request.setAttribute( "data", data );
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher( "/new.jsp" );
        rd.forward( request, response );
        response.getWriter().append( "Served at:" ).append( request.getContextPath() );
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet( request, response );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `requestScope` in `c:out`

`<c:out value="${requestScope.data}">`

For detailed example you can refer: https://www.journaldev.com/2090/jstl-tutorial-jstl-tags-example

I think you are directly calling `/new.jsp`!
For getting value you need to call the servlet URL.
That will fix your problem because on servlet request is despatched to  `/new.jsp` with attribute value `data`.

Comment: ${data} is also not displaying the op

Comment: you need to change `${data}` by `${requestScope.data}`.

Comment: I updated my answer.
Can you call the `servlet` URL. hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: Doing it from servlet url only , i am appending my servlet class name that is naveen on the url

Comment: I am calling from servlet url itself not calling jsp directly u can use the code try it and let me know

Comment: I am doing it from servlet url itself not calling jsp directly

Comment: data is displayed via <%= request.getAttribute("data") %> i want to display it directly ${data}

Comment: Are you using Maven or putting Jar manually in class path? EL jar is mandatory for c tags.

Comment: yes using maven have included the el jar in pom , if i would have not then there would have been a different error in the page itself .

Comment: I think you need to follow all the steps given in: https://www.journaldev.com/2090/jstl-tutorial-jstl-tags-example

Before tying clean the `c:\users\{username}\.m` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your jsp file: Adding **isELIgnored=false**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false" %>
```

This attribute is supposed to be on by default.You can add it to every jsp page to make EL(Expression Language) process successfully.